# ListTile does not show radio buttons in horizontal way in the subtitle

Tags: flutter

I want to display 2 radio buttons horizontally on the subtitle of the ListTile.
I can see only one Radio Button.

```
List<QuestionsOptions> optionsList = [
QuestionsOptions(
  index: 1,
  name: "Yes",
),
QuestionsOptions(
  index: 0,
  name: "No",
),
];


      subtitle:Column(                   
                      children: [
                      new Row(                  
                        children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                            child: Column(
                        children:
                        optionsList.map((data) => RadioListTile(
                          title: Text("${data.name}"),
                          groupValue: 0,
                          value: data.index,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                        //_handleWeightChange(data.name,data.index);
                        },
                      )).toList(),
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
          ),

                    ]),
```

How to display both the radio buttons in horizontal in the subtitle of the Listtile

Comment: Have a look on this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265158/3946958

Comment: The code Snippet worked..!!

Comment: @ravindra the link was more helpful and that was what exactly in wanted in functionality point of view

Answer (score 6):

You can set a Row of `RadioListTile` in the subTitle of the ListTile. You can then use HashMap to track the selected RadioListTile on the List items. The map can be updated when the radio button is clicked. Or if you're using a List for your ListTiles, you can just add the Answer enum on the Object.

```dart
subtitle: Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: RadioListTile<Answer>(
          title: const Text('Yes'),
          value: Answer.yes,
          groupValue: answerVal[index],
          onChanged: (Answer? value) {
            setState(() {
              // Update map value on tap
              answerVal[index] = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: RadioListTile<Answer>(
          title: const Text('No'),
          value: Answer.no,
          groupValue: answerVal[index],
          onChanged: (Answer? value) {
            setState(() {
              answerVal[index] = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image: Demo]

Here's the complete sample

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

enum Answer { yes, no }

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<int, Answer?> answerVal = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return ListTile(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            title: const Text('Question?'),
            subtitle: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile<Answer>(
                      title: const Text('Yes'),
                      value: Answer.yes,
                      groupValue: answerVal[index],
                      onChanged: (Answer? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          answerVal[index] = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: RadioListTile<Answer>(
                      title: const Text('No'),
                      value: Answer.no,
                      groupValue: answerVal[index],
                      onChanged: (Answer? value) {
                        setState(() {
                          answerVal[index] = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```